# Wrap json to convenient python model class

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing python wrapper for some API. I would like to have python class to wrap json objects responded by server.

Let's say server sends back json:

```py
{
  'id': 'id',
  'nested': [
    {'key1': 'key1',
     'nested2': [{'k1': 'k1'}, {'k1': 'k2'}]}
   ]
}
```

I'm looking for a convenient way to modify that data and send back to server. It is important to preserve dict structure.
So I came up with a class:

```py
class Model(collections.UserDict):
    def __init__(self, json_dict):
        super().__init__(json_dict)

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self["id"]

    @id.setter
    def id(self, val):
        self["id"] = val

    @property
    def nested(self):
        return self["nested"]

    @nested.setter
    def nested(self, val):
        # cant set directly because we have to preserve dict structure
        raise AttributeError("cannot set directly")

    def set_k1(self, k1):
        # method to get to nested fields, ex:
        self["nested"][0]["nested2"][0]["k1"] = k1

    # rest of setters
```

I don't want to make user to write code like:

```py
m = Model(json)
m["id"] = "new id"
m["nested"][0]["nested2"][0]["k1"] = "new k1"
```

So thanks to my class user can do:

```py
m.id = "new id"
m.set_k1("new k1")
```

Some pros:

```
- nice way to set values to base keys
- fields known before runtime so IDE can suggest fields
```

cons:

```
- ugly methods to set nested fields
```

I'm looking for any ideas how to make it better. Or even, if it would be possible to use:
`m.nested[0].nested2[0].k1 = "new k1"`

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong here if this works. If you're looking for improvements, you'll need to be a little more specific about what you want to improve. Note that requests for reviewing working code are more typically handled by codereview.se, but be sure to read their documentation first to verify that your question is on topic.

Comment: If I was using your code I would prefer to use just normal json (i.e. dicts and lists). It is much easier for me to read and manipulate. Add a comment to show the developers the format and before the json goes to the server run it through a validator to make sure its proper.